# Blueimp jQuery File Upload Audio/Video restriction

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation, blueimp, regex-lookarounds

Can anyone please tell me how can I restrict audio/video file upload using Blueimp jQuery File upload?

I found the whitelisting using the following option `acceptFileTypes:  /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,` but I want to blacklist audio and video files instead of whitelisting.

I have tried the following to negate .exe and .js files `acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(?!exe|js)$/i` which is restricting all file types regardless of its extensions.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting `$`in wrong place. If you want to find anything except `.exe`, `.js`, use

```
(\.|\/)(?!(exe|js)$)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qP2zY1/2)**

**Reason** :- Lookaheads are of zero width-assertion. It means that they do not consume any characters. In your regex

```
(\.|\/)(?!exe|js)$
```

you are checking for `exe` or `js` just after `.` using lookahead. As soon as it is checked the position resets just after `.`. Now your regex is checking whether it is end of string using `$`. But there is a character left, so it is not end of string and your regex will fail for any extension.

Below, there is some visual to explain for your regex `(\.|\/)(?!exe|js)$`
for string `abcd.jpg`. *(Spaces only for clarity)*

```
    abcd .  jpg
        ^^  ^^ 
        ||  ||
(Matches .) (New position after consuming .)
```

What follows after `.` is `jpg`, which should not be matched to either `exe` or `js` <---*good till here*

As lookahead is of zero-width, the position remains where it is after checking what follows is neither `exe` nor `js`

```
 abcd . jpg
        ^^
        ||
 Check whether its $ i.e. end of string. This is False because we have j. So no match is returned
```

If you want to blacklist audio and video file, here is starter

```
(?:[.\\])(?!(mp3|m4a|wmv|mp4|mkv)$)\w+
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qP2zY1/1)**